# Agregação em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

gostaria de criar um método em minha classe Professor que calculasse o seu salário com base em sua **carga horária**, que é uma função estabelecida na classe Disciplina,  um professor pode lecionar diversas disciplinas, então gostaria que as cargas horárias de cada disciplina que ele leciona fossem acumuladas em uma variável, para que a partir dai pudesse multiplicar pelo valor da hora aula e obter seu salário, no entanto, a forma como eu estou tentando fazer está dando erro, ajudem me por favor:

> classe Professor

```
package agregacao;


public class Professor {

    private String nome;
    private double cpf, salario;
    private Disciplina disciplina;

    public Professor(String nome, double cpf, Disciplina disciplina) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setCpf(double cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public double getCpf() {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public void calcSalario() {
        int carga += this.disciplina.getCargaHoraria();//O erro está nessa linha
    }
}
```

> classe Disciplina

```
package agregacao;

public class Disciplina {

    private String nomeDisciplina;
    private int cargaHoraria;

    public void setNomeDisciplina(String nomeDisciplina) {
        this.nomeDisciplina = nomeDisciplina;
    }

    public String getNomeDisciplina() {
        return this.nomeDisciplina;
    }

    public void setCargaHoraria(int cargaHoraria) {
        this.cargaHoraria = cargaHoraria;
    }

    public int getCargaHoraria() {
        return this.cargaHoraria;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você deve alterar para lista de Disciplinas do professor, já que um professor pode lecionar várias disciplinas:

```
private List<Disciplina> disciplinas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Você pode criar um método na classe Professor para incluir as disciplinas, e invocar o método para calcular o salário.

```
public void addDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
    this.getDisciplinas().add(disciplina);
}

public void calcularSalario() {
    int valorHoraAula = 10;
    for(Disciplina disciplina : getDisciplinas()){
        this.salario += disciplina.getCargaHoraria() * valorHoraAula;
    }
}
```

O valor da hora aula você pode atribuir em uma constante ou se preferir pode criar uma variável para definir isso de forma dinâmica.

Comment: mas com eu acesso meu método da Disciplina getCargaHoraria(); dessa forma?

Answer (score 1):

Existem 2 erros no seu código

O primeiro é que para calcular a carga horária você está incrementando a variável carga, porém ela não foi declarada, e nem dado um valor inicial à ela

O segundo é que como um professor tem várias disciplinas, você tem que manter na Classe Professor uma lista de disciplinas

Dai para calcular a carga horária do professor é necessário percorrer um loop de todas as disciplinas

```
public class Professor {

    private String nome;
    private double cpf, salario;
    private ArrayList<Disciplina> disciplinaLista = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();

    public Professor(String nome, double cpf) { //Você pode passar um arraylist pelo construtor se preferir também
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    //Demais métodos...

    public addDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
         disciplinaLista.add(disciplina);
    }
    public removeDisciplina(Disciplina disciplina){
         disciplinaLista.remove(disciplina);
    }

    public void calcSalario() {
        int carga = 0;
        for(Disciplina disciplina : disciplinaLista){ // Para cada disciplina na lista de disciplinaLista
             carga += disciplina.getCargaHoraria();
        }

    }
}
```

Abraços